# How to watch a mongodb collection from an iOS app that uses a node server to communicate with db

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, mongodb, watch

I am currently creating an iOS app that uses mongodb for storing its data. I am trying to create a real time chat, and one of the things I need to implement is watching a collection to check for new messages. In the app I use post requests to communicate with a node js server that communicates with my db. I am trying to figure out how I could accomplish watching the db with the architecture that I have. Does anyone have any idea how I could solve this issue.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using MongoDB atlas? If so you could use a a stitch app which triggers when your messages collection is updated and tells your app to refresh the chat.

Comment: I am, but eventually it will be many devices connected to the same server, would the stitch app be able to communicate with the specific device to alert it to refresh chat rather than all devices?

Comment: Yes it can do, the trigger will fire on every database insert or update. In the stitch function you would specifiy the device to be alerted using the information from the database, I guess you have some sort of idenfiter for the speicifc device which is attached to the message.

Comment: Great, thank you! I will look into it.